# Performing SVD Feature Decompostion on a Large Sparse Matrix

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, sparse-matrix, svd, lsa

I saved my features from text data with pickle in sparse matrix format with a shape of (323549, 4119259). I am trying to perform Singular Value Decomposition on them using the sklearn library, however, I keep getting a memory error which suggests that my computer isn't powerful enough to perform the feature reduction. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? This is the code I used.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
import pickle


with open('vectors.pickle') as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'wb')
    matrix = pickle.load(f) #Loads the TF-IDF Vectors



print('LSAING . . .')
lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=300, n_iter=10) #Perform the Feature Reduction
lsa.fit(matrix)

matrix_T = lsa.fit_transform(matrix)

print('Dumping')
with open('lsa.pickle', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(lsa, f) #Dumps the new features
```

I am using an i7-5500 processor with 8GB of RAM.

Comment: In my case,  I use large swap space as a workaround.

Comment: So do you recommend that I increase my swap partition?

Comment: Maybe give a try to sklearn.decomposition.NMF, in case it better deals with sparsity, as it is a sparse method by nature.

Comment: See this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41259/how-to-compute-svd-of-a-huge-sparse-matrix

Comment: You can also try reducing the number of components to e.g. 150

Comment: I've tried increasing my swap partition, and that still ended up with a memory error. I've also tried reducing the components. The problem with this is, I tried about 50, and that only had a total explained variance ratio of about 0.09, and I want an explained variance of about 0.7 to maintain optimal dimensionality.

Comment: You can try using [sparsesvd](https://pypi.org/project/sparsesvd/)